# Обновление кэша в Yii2

Tags: yii2, bootstrap

В общем-то в один момент столкнулся с проблемой перегрузки JS и CSS кэша в Yii2. Однако, по своей глупости я не использовал 'appendTimestamp' => true.

Я использовал $forceCopy = true

Основная проблема в том, что мои стили не были записаны в отдельном CSS'e, а был отредактирован файл bootstrap.css, который при форс-копировании, по всей видимости, обновился до исходного. Так выглядят зависимости моего ассета:

```
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
];
```

Верно ли я утверждаю, что теперь отредактированный в папке web/assets/*буквы-цифры*/css файл bootstrap.css с моими стилями вернуть невозможно? Зачем вообще приложение использует такой вид ассетов и папок вместо обычных стилей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут дело в том, что в web/assets/ комплектуются пакеты из ресурсов. Ресурсы в свою очередь хранятся в другом месте (иногда они недоступны из web). Например, при подключении стороннего модуля, все его ресурсы css и js лежат где-то в /vendor/user/bla/bla/bla. Чтобы подключить их на страницу, фреймворк копирует комплект ресурсов в web/assets/bla и подключает к странице. По сути можно удалить все директории из web/assets/ и они (или символьные ссылки) будут сгенерированы вновь при необходимости.

Как правило, редактируют источники ресурсов (css и js), а не их готовые комплекты. bootstrap.css можно вернуть, если используется система контроля версий. Также в шторме есть возможность просмотра локальной истории изменения файлов проекта. Вполне может быть в других редакторах есть такая же возможность.

[Подробнее про комплекты ресурсов для yii2](https://p0vidl0.info/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-structure-assets.html)